# r comparison operator is not working for a very simple code

Tags: r, filter, double, comparison, operators

[image: Sample Data]

[image: Sample Code]

The filter in the first picture is clearly not working. None of the rows are filtered. However, in the second picture, there are clearly much less rows that satisfy the condition average value < good(blue) than the first picture.
Why is the code in the first picture not working and what may be a possible solution?

Comment: Can you try using single quotes in your code (or even better: use standard names without whitespace or brackets in which case you can get rid of the quotation marks in your code).

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. Do not post pictures of data or code. We can't copy/paste those values into R for testing.

Comment: I've tried single quotes but they aren't working.  Also, I cant produce a reproducible example. Because filter has worked without any problem until now and I can't seem to identify what the problem is for such as simple code.